# Transcription of an 1835 will entry in Prerogative Court of Canterbury Wills record

Tags: 19th-century, will, transcriptions

I have transcribed the will of a likely ancestor in a tree I am building for a friend, but can't get one last word.
Can anyone tell me what the word is? It is just three words from the end, between "first sworn by" and "duly to administer."
Please see below images:
[image: Last Will and Testament of John Edgson 1 of 3]
[image: Last Will and Testament of John Edgson 2 of 3]
[image: Last Will and Testament of John Edgson 3 of 3]

This is my transcription:
https://1drv.ms/w/s!ApdG6p7a4nWmgs8IvonfWU0Imuk-nA?e=Jdh6GM

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word is "*comon*", and was used here as an abbreviation of the word "*commission*".  The phrase:

> "...  to whom administration was granted having been sworn by commission duly to administer."

being a standard one in wills of that period.

---

This not an unusual abbreviation in this context, although personally I have found the simpler "*com*" or "*comm*" to be more often used for "*commission*".

Similarly, (as you noted in your transcript) "*admon*" is used as an abbreviation for "*administration*" earlier in that paragraph.